# Netbeans project - Node.js: Node must be a valid file

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans

I’ve just created my first Node.js application in Netbeans.  I mean, this is a brand new project.  I haven't done anything and I’m already getting an error.  Maybe there is a step to configure this or a file to create or something to install but I've googled for information to no avail.  I guess this is just too basic, because I couldn’t find anything out there to help.

[image]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you install nodejs ? Can you put the result of `node -v` ?

Comment: Yes:  node -v
v4.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh!  I found it.  For some reason the Node path and the npm path were defaulting to Program Files (x86) and nodejs was installed in Program Files.  **I feel dumb.**

Plus, as soon as I fixed it, all other new projects were fixed.